# Sql Server to MySql Data Migration

Tags: mysql, sql-server, data-migration

I have been given the enviable task of migrating a legacy SQL Server 2000 database to MySql. The two databases have enitrely different structures. I only have to migrate data i.e no stored procedures etc.

I have created a 'clean' MySql database i.e. an database with empty tables with the schema of the new system.

I am planning on using the MySql Migration toolkit to first convert the Sql Server database to MySql.

Then I want to pull the data from the old database to the new. I have broken down the database into conceptually independent sections that can be migrated independently. This is where i'm not sure what to do. Do I just have to write sql scripts to transfer? These scripts would contain big cursors to transfer the data e.g. I have a list of Organizations and users linked to the organizations. Should I write a cursor to insert each organization and users in turn into the new database or are there tools to help me do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use SQL Server DTS. You'll need to install the ODBC Drivers for MySQL. This [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966396.aspx) explains the reverse (MySQL to SQL) but if you reverse the source and target the article explains what you need to do pretty well.

Comment: Hi Conrad,Thanks for your reply. I had a look into a DTS package and it only seems that it allows me to migrate the data to a table with the same structure in the destination database. e.g. In my source db I have a table called tblOrganization and in my destination I have a table called Organization which has a totally different structure to the old table. It is just the data I need to migrate. Do you know if there is any tool to help do transforms like this or does it have to be done in SQL?

Comment: DTS (Data Transformation Services) is indeed a tool to help in transformations. Take a look at "Tasks: Defining Steps in a Package" in this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917688.aspx)